# KivyMD create_project - Can't change screen on button release

Tags: python, model-view-controller, kivy, kivymd

I'm using kivymd create_project with the mvc pattern... which I don't fully understand. I have watched videos, read the wiki on mvc but it doesn't quite make sense to me when i look at my kivy project.

I'm having a hard time switching from my main screen to my second screen.

main.kv

```
<MainScreenView>
    NavCard:
        id: events
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'event screen'
```

screens.py

```
screens = {
    "main screen": {
        "model": MainScreenModel,
        "controller": MainScreenController,
    },
    "event screen": {
        "model": EventScreenModel,
        "controller": EventScreenController,
    }
}
```

main.py

```
class TheCWA(MDApp):
    KV_DIRS = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "View")]
   

    def build_app(self) -> MDScreenManager:
        """
        In this method, you don't need to change anything other than the
        application theme.
        """

        import View.screens
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Cyan'
        self.manager_screens = MDScreenManager()
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
        importlib.reload(View.screens)
        screens = View.screens.screens

        for i, name_screen in enumerate(screens.keys()):
            model = screens[name_screen]["model"]()
            controller = screens[name_screen]["controller"](model)
            view = controller.get_view()
            view.screen_manager = self.manager_screens
            view.name = name_screen
            self.manager_screens.add_widget(view)

        return self.manager_screens
```

so i'll admit, I get confused in the screen manager stuff and the enemuerate stuff. This is all code that is auto inserted when you run the kivymd create_project command

the navcard is a MDCard and will press but does not change screens. If i comment out the mainscreen in the screens.py, i can get my event screen to show.

From the event screen, I can switch to the main screen using a lambda function. (another thing that is a little above my understanding of coding)

```
<EventScreenView>
    name: 'event screen'

    MDTopAppBar:
        title: 'Events'
        md_bg_color: 'white'
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        left_action_items:[['chevron-left', lambda x: root.controller.on_chevron_back()]]
```

controller/event_list.py

```
class EventListScreenController:

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        self.view = View.EventListScreen.event_list.EventListScreenView(
            controller=self, model=self.model
        )

    def on_chevron_back(self):
        self.view.manager_screens.current = 'main screen'
```

Any help figuring out how to get to my event screen from the navcard button is super appreciated. I didn't wanna overload the amount of code. The MainScreenView just inherits from the basescreen (all template) let me know if you theres something relevant that I didn't include.

Answer (score 0):

```
<MainScreenView>
    NavCard:
        id: events
        on_release: root.screen_manager.current = 'event screen'
```

This should work. or

```
<MainScreenView>
    NavCard:
        id: events
        on_release: app.manager_screens.current = 'event screen'
```